# Transfer ownership from std::vector to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013

I have a function `foo` that takes a `std::vector<char>` as an argument and calls another function `bar` that takes a `std::shared_ptr<char>` as an argument.

```
void foo(std::vector<char> arg)
{
    bar(?) // what do i pass to bar here?
}

void bar(std::shared_ptr<char> arg)
{
    // do something asynchronously
}
```

How do I transfer ownership of the vector's underlying array to the shared_ptr?

The vector is large (4MB), so I would like to avoid copying from the vector into another char array.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<char>` is a pointer to a single character.  It can't own an array of `char`.

Comment: @japreiss: Actually it can, because the deleter of `std::shared_ptr` is type erased. If it is constructed like this `std::shared_ptr<char>(new char[65535], std::default_delete<char[]>());`, then it is perfect valid. But I doubt OP actually does this.

Comment: @japreiss More to the point: is there _ever_ any reason to have a pointer (smart or otherwise) to a `char`?

Comment: @tcb What are you gaining from the `vector<char>` to `shared_ptr<char[]>` conversion?

Comment: I only own `foo`, the vector is passed to me from another library, and I have to pass this on to `bar` which resides in another library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. There's no way to release a vector's ownership of its memory apart from moving it to another vector.

If you could modify `bar` to take `std::vector<char>`, then you could transfer ownership by moving the vector, without copying it.